# How best to handle data fetching needed for FluentValidation

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, mediatr

In the app I'm working on, I'm using Mediatr and its pipelines to handle database interaction, some minor business logic, validation, etc.

There's a few checks for things like access control I can handle in the pipeline, since I'm using a context object as described here https://jimmybogard.com/sharing-context-in-mediatr-pipelines/ to go from ASP.Net identity to a custom context object with user information and claims.

One problem I'm having is that since this application is multi-tenant, I need to ensure that even if an object exists, it belongs to that tenant, and the only way to be sure of that is to grab the object from the database and check it. It seems to me the validation shouldn't have side effects, so I don't want to rely on that to populate the context object. But then that pushes a bunch of validation down into the Mediatr handlers as they check for object existence, and so on, leading to a lot of repeated code. I don't really want to query the database multiple times since some queries can be expensive.

Another issue with doing the more complicated validation in the actual request handlers is getting what are essentially validation errors back out. Currently, if one of these checks fail I throw a `ValidationException`, which is then caught by middleware and turned into a `ProblemDetails` that's returned to the API caller. This is basically exceptions as flow control, and a validation failure really isn't "exceptional" anyhow.

The thoughts I'm having on how to solve this are:

1. Somewhere in the pipeline, when I'm building the context, include attempting to fetch the objects needed from the database. Validation then fails if any of these are null. This seems like it would make testing harder, as well as needing to decorate the requests somehow (or use reflection) so the pipeline can know to attempt to load these objects.
2. Have the queries in the validator, but use some sort of cache aware repository so when the same object is queried later, it's served from the cache, and not the database. The handlers would also use this cache aware repository (Currently the handlers interact directly with the EF Core DbContext to query). This then adds the issue of cache invalidation, which I'm going to have to handle at some point, anyhow (quite a few items are seldom modified). For testing, a dummy cache object can be injected that doesn't actually cache anything.
3. Make all the responses from requests implement an interface (or extend an abstract class) that has validation info, general success flags, etc. This can either be returned through the API directly, or have some pipeline that transforms failures into `ProblemDetails`. This would add some boilerplate to every response and handler, but avoids exceptions as flow control, and the caching/reflection issues in the other options.

Assume for 1 and 2 that any sort of race conditions are not an issue. Objects don't change owners, and things are seldom actually deleted from the database for auditing/accounting purposes.

I know there's no true one size fits all for problems like this, but I would like to know if there's additional options I'm missing, or any long term maintainability issues anyone with a similar pipeline has encountered if they went with one of these listed options.

Answer (score 6):

We use MediatR IRequestPreProcessor for fetching data that we need both in RequestHandler and in FluentValidation validators.

RequestPreProcessor:

```csharp
    public interface IProductByIdBinder
    {
        int ProductId { get; }
        ProductEntity Product { set; }
    }

    public class ProductByIdBinder<T> : IRequestPreProcessor<T> where T : IProductByIdBinder
    {
        private readonly IRepositoryReadAsync<ProductEntity> productRepository;

        public ProductByIdBinder(IRepositoryReadAsync<ProductEntity> productRepository)
        {
            this.productRepository = productRepository;
        }

        public async Task Process(T request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Product = await productRepository.GetAsync(request.ProductId);
        }
    }
```

RequestHandler:

```csharp
 public class ProductDeleteCommand : IRequest, IProductByIdBinder
    {
        public ProductDeleteCommand(int id)
        {
            ProductId = id;
        }

        public int ProductId { get; }
        public ProductEntity Product { get; set; }

        private class ProductDeleteCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<ProductDeleteCommand>
        {
            private readonly IRepositoryAsync<ProductEntity> productRepository;

            public ProductDeleteCommandHandler(
                IRepositoryAsync<ProductEntity> productRepository)
            {
                this.productRepository = productRepository;
            }
            
            public Task<Unit> Handle(ProductDeleteCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                productRepository.Delete(request.Product);
                
                return Unit.Task;
            }
        }
    }
```

FluentValidation validator:

```csharp
 public class ProductDeleteCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<ProductDeleteCommand>
    {
        public ProductDeleteCommandValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(cmd => cmd)
                .Must(cmd => cmd.Product != null)
                .WithMessage(cmd => $"The product with id {cmd.ProductId} doesn't exist.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with handling business logic validation in the handler layer.
Moreover, I do not think it is right to throw exceptions for them, as you said it is exceptions as flow control.

Introducing a cache seems like overkill for the use case too. The most reasonable option is the third IMHO.

Instead of implementing an interface you can use the nifty `OneOf` library and have something like

```
    using HandlerResponse = OneOf<Success, NotFound, ValidationResponse>;

    public class MediatorHandler : IRequestHandler<Command, HandlerResponse>
    {
       public async Task<HandlerResponse> Handle(
        Command command,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Resource resource = await _userRepository
            .GetResource(command.Id);

        if (resource is null)
            return new NotFound();

        if (!resource.IsValid)
            return new ValidationResponse(new ProblemDetails());

        return new Success();
    }
```

And then map it in your API Layer like

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] DummyRequest request)
    {
        HandlerResponse response = await _mediator.Send(
            new Command(request.Id));

        return response.Match<IActionResult>(
            success => Created(),
            notFound => NotFound(),
            failed => new UnprocessableEntityResult(failed.ProblemDetails))
        );
    }
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the OneOf library. Discriminated unions are something I've grown to love in TypeScript and missed in C#. I'll give this a try and see how well it fits.